# Vuejs class binding not working on initial render

Tags: class, data-binding, vue.js, v-for

I am having an strange issue with VueJS not setting a class on an item within a v-for loop when the page first loads.  It works after I click on it to toggle the selected attribute on and off, but when selected is initially true, the row is not highlighted.  Thus, it takes 2 clicks to "sync" the screen to the data.

```
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="v in listOfItems" :key="v.id" :class="{ selected: v.selected }" v-on:click="function(){ itemSelected(v) }">
     <td style="text-align:right"><span v-text="v.selected"></span></td>
     <td style="text-align:right"><span v-text="v.label"></span></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>

function itemSelected(row) {
    row.selected = !row.selected
    app.$nextTick(function() {
        console.log( $('tr.selected').length )
    })
    return false
}
```

The array is initially loaded before the screen is displayed with:

```
app.listOfItems = [{
    id: 100,
    label: 'Item 100',
    selected: true
}]
```

All other data is displayed correctly, and even selected shows true in the table cell.  Only the "selected" class is not being applied initially until I click twice (once to unselect and again to reselect).

Comment: Why not just `v-on:click="v.selected = !v.selected"`?

Comment: Can you clarify what "before the screen is displayed" means?  When exactly in the Vue lifecycle are you loading the `listOfItems`?

Answer (score 1):

Putting your code into a snippet here, it works as expected. Your problem probably relates to how you load `listOfItems`, but it is hard to say. You might want to copy this snippet and see if you can introduce more of your original code process to see if you can reproduce your error.

Making a snippet like this is a good idea in all kinds of ways: it may help you discover the problem yourself; it can establish whether the problem is in the code you think it's in; it gives you practice; it gives potential answerers a starting point. I do wish more people would do it.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    listOfItems: [{
      id: 100,
      label: 'Item 100',
      selected: true
    }]
  },
  methods: {
    itemSelected(row) {
      row.selected = !row.selected
      app.$nextTick(function() {
        console.log($('tr.selected').length)
      })
      return false
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<table id="app">
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="v in listOfItems" :key="v.id" :class="{ selected: v.selected }" v-on:click="function(){ itemSelected(v) }">
      <td style="text-align:right"><span v-text="v.selected"></span></td>
      <td style="text-align:right"><span v-text="v.label"></span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the replies.  I'll try to address each comment:  First, the reason for the function instead of inline toggling is the function does other things related to the app - removed here for simplicity.  As for using the code snippet, I did not know about this feature of SO until now, so thanks.  Finally as for how or when listOfItems is loaded, why would the "when" matter?  When I check it in the debug console, the values are correct.  Isn't reactivity supposed to do its thing whenever the data is loaded?  Your snippet does appear to work, so I'm very confused why not mine.

Comment: Reactivity will do its thing if the data is loaded in such a way as to be reactive. It is possible that you have [inserted data in a non-reactive way](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats), although I don't know what would subsequently make it reactive as you describe.

Comment: I found the issue.  A transition function that runs when moving from one screen to the next in my SPA had a line to reset all selected classes, regardless of the data model!  It was $('.selected').removeClass('selected') which the framework ran at page load.  Tricky to find.  So Vue's reactivity was working after all.  Sorry for the rabbit hole but I do appreciate all the help!